# Native Wind not working with expo project in ReactNaive

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, nativewind

Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Despite trying various solutions, I'm puzzled as to why Tailwind isn't functioning properly in my ReactNative expo project.

**here is my App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreens from './screens/HomeScreens';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white">
      <StatusBar style="dark" />
      <Text className="text-red-600">Apps</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
"nativewind/babel",
    ],
  };
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./App/**/*.{js,jsx,ts}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "awesomeproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "49.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "private": true
}

Please Guide me
```

I tried everything which I could so far

Comment: Can you try generating an output.css file by running `npx tailwind -o output.css` in your terminal?

Comment: It's fixed now by just deleting node modules and re-install native wind node modules

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting your cache

```
npx expo start --clear
```